# Using fit_params in neuraxle pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neuraxle

I want to use a classifier, e.g. the `sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier`, within a neuraxle pipeline and fit it in an online fashion using `partial_fit`. I have the classifier wrapped in an
`SKLearnWrapper` with `use_partial_fit=True`, like this:

```py
from neuraxle.pipeline import Pipeline
from neuraxle.steps.sklearn import SKLearnWrapper
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

p = Pipeline([
    SKLearnWrapper(SGDClassifier(), use_partial_fit=True)
    ]
)

X = [[1.], [2.], [3.]]
y = ['class1', 'class2', 'class1']

p.fit(X, y)
```

However, to fit the classifier in online fashion, one needs to provide an additional argument `classes` to the `partial_fit` function, that contains the possible classes that are occurring in the data, e.g. `classes=['class1', 'class2']`, at least for the first time it is called. So the above code results in an error:

```
ValueError: classes must be passed on the first call to partial_fit.
```

The same issue arises for other `fit_params` like `sample_weight`. In a standard sklearn pipeline, `fit_params` can be handed down to individual steps via the <step name>__<parameter name> syntax, e.g. for the `sample_weight` parameter:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

q = Pipeline([
    ('clf', SGDClassifier())
])

q.fit(X, y, clf__sample_weight=[0.25, 0.5, 0.25])
```

Of course, the standard sklearn pipeline does not allow to call partial_fit on the classifier, which is why I want to use the neuraxle pipeline in the first place.

Is there any way to hand additional parameters to the `fit` or `partial_fit` functions of a step in a neuraxle pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you edit the [SKLearnWrapper](https://github.com/Neuraxio/Neuraxle/blob/1568385cf847bf54939378299a938ec580642df3/neuraxle/steps/sklearn.py#L39) so as to add arguments to the partial_fit method by redefining it and to add the missing arguments you would like to have.

You could also add a method to this forked SKLearnWrapper as follow. The classes arguments could be changed using an [apply](https://www.neuraxle.org/stable/api/neuraxle.base.html?highlight=apply#neuraxle.base._HasRecursiveMethods.apply) method called from outside the pipeline later on.

```py
ConfigurablePartialSGDClassifier(SKLearnWrapper)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(SGDClassifier(), use_partial_fit=True)

    def update_classes(self, classes: List[str]):
        self.classes = classes

    def _sklearn_fit_without_expected_outputs(self, data_inputs):
        self.wrapped_sklearn_predictor.partial_fit(data_inputs, classes=self.classes)
```

You can then do:

```py
p = Pipeline([
    ('clf', ConfigurablePartialSGDClassifier())
])

X1 = [[1.], [2.], [3.]]
X2 = [[4.], [5.], [6.]]
Y1 = [0, 1, 1]
Y2 = [1, 1, 0]
classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class1']

p.apply("update_classes", classes)
p.fit(X1, Y1)
p.fit(X2, Y2)
```

Note that `p` could also simply have been defined this way to get the same behavior:

```py
p = ConfigurablePartialSGDClassifier()
```

The thing is, calls to apply methods can pass through pipelines and are applied to all nested steps if the steps contain such methods.